# Kendo Pivot Grid loose filters after changes to rows columns or measures

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, pivot, datasource

i have create a [Kendo Pivot Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid/index) like the example. Also inside dataSource i have add fitler 
`filter: {
    "field": "[Geography].[City]",
    "operator": "eq",
    "value": "Auburn"
}`

[dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uFEze)

In this example works perfect, but in my App doesn't and i have no clue! The basic problem is that every time that i change a row column or measure from configurator or toolbar datasource seems to forget filter property and load all items without any filter. Has anyone a idea about what maybe happens? I am stack here :/

Answer (score 0):

I update kendo.all.min.js to latest version and works, probably this was bug but seems they have fixed it.